# Novel about a trio of children with strange powers who team up to get rid of a strict nanny

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in elementary school, but I can't remember the name. Here's a few things I can remember: A man (who already has a daughter) gets married to a goth lady with three kids. One of the new step-siblings is a little girl who can seemingly turn into a cat; the middle child is a scientist who does crazy experiments; and the oldest child is thought to be a vampire. The entire book is written from the POV of the man's daughter. In the book, the parents go off on their honeymoon and hire a military nanny who is very strict, and the kids team up to get rid of her.

That's all I can remember.

Comment: Are there 3 kids or 4?  You mention the woman's 3 kids and the man's daughter.

Comment: And when were you in elementary school? Did the book seem new then? Was the book short or long? Were there illustrations? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: @Emma C  Get rid of the srict nanny?  You mean drive her away?  Or do you mean eliminate her?

Comment: i ended up stumbling on the book not long after!! the series is called meet the kreeps :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the OP's comment above, this was the [Meet the Kreeps series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/115279-meet-the-kreeps) by [Kiki Thorpe](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?35784).

The titles of the series include:

- There Goes the Neighborhood (2008)
- The New Step-Mummy (2008)
- The Nanny Nightmare (2009)
- The Mad Scientist (2009)
- Three's A Krowd (2009)